# Specific targeting with jQuery hover not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to grab using jQuery the `.hover()` event for `#sidebar-wrapper` only when `#page-wrapper` has a class of `toggled-2`.

```
<div id="page-wrapper" class="toggled-2">

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">

    <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
      <li id="organisation"><a href="/organisation"><span class="menu-icon-stack glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>Select Business</a></li>
      <li>....</li>
      <li class="active">
         <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-stacked sub-nav nav-list">
             <li>....</li>
             <li class="sub-active">Active menu item</li>
             <li>....</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

   </div>
 </div>
```

My latest jQuery attempt is this (no errors, but does not execute):

```
$("#page-wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper").hover(
    function() {
        alert("hover active!");
    },
    function() {
        alert("hover off!");
    }
);
```

This code executes the alerts, but it is not specific in its targeting so it also triggers the alerts when the `toggled-2` class has not been applied to `#page-wrapper`:

```
$("#sidebar-wrapper").hover(
    function() {
        alert("hover active!");
    },
    function() {
        alert("hover off!");
    }
);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does not execute? it works for me @ https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/h3er5q6m/

Comment: Is `.toggle-2` going to be on other things you don't want to alert?  If so you could just remove `#page-wrapper` from the identifier.  Otherwise you could set `.toggle-2` as an id and just use that as the identifier.  Else you could use the `find()` method to find the `.toggle-2` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your event to #sidebar-wrapper but conditionally check the parent (#page-wrapper) to see whether it has the required class or not.

```
$("#sidebar-wrapper").hover(function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("toggled-2")) {
        alert("Hover active!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @fridge_light, this was the only solution that did the trick!

Comment: Great. I'd recommend this approach because it means you can add/remove classes from the parent as many times as you want - you only need to bind the hover event once.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
$("div#page-wrapper.toggled-2 > #sidebar-wrapper").hover(
    function() {
        console.log("hover active!");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("hover off!");
    }
);
```

Or

```
$("div#page-wrapper.toggled-2").find("#sidebar-wrapper").hover(
    function() {
        console.log("hover active!");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("hover off!");
    }
);
```

This should be more specific. Your second bit of code would execute anytime that div is hovered over.